# What is Warn and Error about Rotate recovery?

Tags: ros, navigation, local-planner, global-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After planning, ROS outputs a warn and an error on a terminal.

```
[WARN] [1403639144.542396993]: Rotate recovery behavior started.
[ERROR] [1403639144.542945771]: Rotate recovery can't rotate in place because there is a potential collision. Cost: -1.00
```

What outputs these warning and error? I means which source file says error and warning? and What kind of problem happens on my plan?
Could anyone give me any clues? Thank you in advance?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174851/what-is-warn-and-error-about-rotate-recovery?/) by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 894 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this in the rotate_recovery behavior inside the navigation stack. However, the actual cause of this is typically more complex. If your robot has an odd-shaped footprint, than that can be the cause. But if you are using a turtlebot, with a circular footprint and centered drive wheels, you should pretty much always be able to rotate in place -- unless localization drifts/jumps, thus putting you on top of an obstacle that was already in the cost map.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-25**:
Thanks @fergs, I try to experiment a navigation with turtlebot2. As Turtlebot2 can rotate in place, you say that such a error doesn't arise without drift/jumps?

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-09-18**:
@fergs, I run into this situation quite often with my Kobuki when it is stopped in a hallway and needs to go to the next goal location.  I am using amcl and an existing map for localization and the DWA global planner.  Is there any way to force a rotation in place as a last resort recovery behavior?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I means which source file says error and warning?

```
grep -R "Rotate recovery behavior started." /opt/ros/groovy/
/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/navigation/rotate_recovery/src/rotate_recovery.cpp:  ROS_WARN("Rotate recovery behavior started.");
Binary file /opt/ros/groovy/stacks/navigation/rotate_recovery/lib/librotate_recovery.so matches
```

---

Originally posted by [MichaelKorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/905/michaelkorn/) with karma: 1480 on 2014-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-06-27**:
Thanks you @MichaelKorn, The command is useful for me.